# c++ "const T &const" What is the meaning of the 2nd const?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Could you please explain me the meaning of the second "const" in the following expression:

```
int i = 42;
const int &const ri = i;
```

Are there some cases where const T &const is mandatory?

What I understood so far:
Pointers are objects, and they can be reassigned.

```
int i = 42;
const int *ptr1 = &i;        // valid: (low-level const): *ptr1 cannot be changed.
int *const ptr2 = &i;        // valid: (high-level const): ptr2 cannot be changed.
const int *const ptr3 = &i:  // also valid (combination of 2 precedent lines).
```

References, unliked pointers are not objects (they have no address) and cannot be reassigned ==> no meaning for an "high-level const"

```
int i = 42;
int &ri1 = i;        // valid: ri1 is a new name for i
const int &ri2 = 7;  // valid and const is required
const int &ri3 = i;  // valid, what is the use of const?

const int &const ri4 = i;  // valid, has the second const an importance?
```

Comment: That doesn't/shouldn't compile AFAIK.

Comment: [GCC doesn't compile that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3867181d9500752)

Comment: Ok. It use Visual Studio Express 2013 (I don't know what compiler is used by default but it compiled) so I thought it was correct and I wanted to understand what it is used for.

Comment: @user3019338: it should give you a warning (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydx93b5s.aspx) - if you're not seeing that, make sure you turn the warning settings right up.

Comment: Side note: Any leading 'const T' is actually 'T const'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form `int & const` is ill-formed (C++11 §8.3.2):

> In a declaration T D where D has either of the forms
>
> ```
> & attribute-specifier-seqopt D1  
> && attribute-specifier-seqopt D1
> ```
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration T D1 is “derived-declarator-type-list T,” then the type of the identifier of D is “derived-declarator-type-list reference to T.” The optional attribute-specifier-seq appertains to the reference type. **Cv-qualified references are ill-formed** except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers
> are ignored.

So no, it can't be mandatory anywhere. And it has no semantics.